# Testing for mean differences in time series

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, anova

I've checked the past posts in the forum, but none of them was satisfactory for my problem. I have to divide a time series into sub-intervals, then I have to test for mean differences between these intervals. The problem is that since it is a time series, there is autocorrelation, therefore I cannot use the classical Anova and t-test (or Wilcoxon or others) which require independence. I need a test to make pairwise comparisons (such as the t-test) and one for multiple comparisons (such as the Anova) which don't require Independence (and preferably also for non-normal data and non-constant in variance data). Do you have any suggestion? It must be hypothesis testing not other procedure, thanks for your help.

Comment: Replace the vanilla standard error with HAC robust standard error and you should be fine.

Comment: Is it possible to adjust with the HAC correction a t-test and the Anova? Is it implemented in R or Excel (via macros)? Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For pairwise comparison**
Define a new variable as the difference between the two original variables. If you can reasonably assume it has stable properties (the data generating process does not change) within the sub-interval, then you do two things:

- Run a regression of the new variable on a constant alone and use HAC robust standard errors in a $t$-test of the null hypothesis that the slope coefficient equals zero.
  This approach is relatively robust against model misspecification but the drawback is it also has less power to detect differences from zero.
- You could model the new variable with ARMA-GARCH and look at whether the intercept in the ARMA model is significantly different from zero.
  This approach is relatively less robust against model misspecification but has more power to detect differences from zero.

If you get the same result from both approaches, it would be encouraging. If the results differ, you might want to inspect this deeper. E.g. if you reject the null hypothesis in the ARMA-GARCH but fail to reject in the HAC appraoch, you may look carefully whether the parametric model is justified and decide on whether to rely on it or to go with the more robust approach.

Both approaches can be implemented with the use of existing packages in R (I believe, `sandwich` and `rugarch`).

Comment: This seems to me a good solution, I give you more information. The sub-intervals are obtained from a log-difference Series to make it stationary. The sub-intervals which I want to compare are of 15 observation for each, does this affect the power of the result in some way? When I take the difference between two sub -intervals (say X and Y) I obtain the new variable X-Y, when I test the slope am I considering the difference between the two means? Thank you.

Comment: @Kolmogorovwannabe, regarding *...am I considering the difference between the two means?*, the answer is Yes. Regarding the subsamples being so small (just 15 observations), there is no point in fitting an ARMA-GARCH model. I doubt HAC errors would be particularly helpful either. Unless you get a good estimate of autocorrelation from somewhere else (using some additional information besides the 15 points), you might be stuck...

Comment: Anova and t-test were perfect for my purposes, unfortunately I can't find a replacement when the assumption of independence is violated. Your help was precious but I can't see a solution at this point. Is there some other way to test for significative differences between subsamples from the same time series? Maybe something near to the idea of the above mentioned tests. Thank you.

Comment: The solution with HAC robust standard errors is as close as it gets to the $t$-test, because it is the same $t$-test but based on appropriately adjusted standard errors. I would say, it *is* a (if not *the*) replacement when the assumption of independence is violated. As such, I would consider it to be "near the idea" of the vanilla $t$-test. The problem with the small sample size will be a problem for any test you consider instead, just like it is a problem in the approach I have suggested.

Comment: What could it be a good dimension of the sample to have better results? I was thinking to increase the sample a bit. It is possible to apply some correction For small samples?

Comment: The problem is that a small sample contains little information. Trying to correct that based on that limited information will not work. One idea: if some key features of the autocorrelation stay the same over the whole sample, you could try estimating them from the whole sample. You could then apply the estimates of the relevant parameters on a particular subsample to get the HAC robust errors, for example.

Comment: I haven't undestand your last suggestion, but the dimension of the sample don't worry me too much because I'm interested only to the information contained in that small period. For the Anova the are no alternatives?

Comment: The sample size becomes a problem when you want to test a hypothesis about it. There is too little information to make strong statements such as "I reject a null hypothesis of equal means with 95% confidence". Because of the size of the sample, your confidence will be, say, just 50% instead. For comparing multiple series, you could construct a robustified $F$-test using the same logic as for the robustified $t$-test, but I do not have an idea ready on how exactly to do that.

Comment: I will work on it, you helped me a lot! However for my purposes I want to compare two subsamples, one made of 15 days before a date T, and one made of 15 days after that same date, to say, after the test, if the Series showed a different behavior after that date. I'm only focused on the information given by those 15 days before and after, in this sense I think that the dimension should not be a big problem because it is needed given the nature of this experiment.

Comment: You are welcome! What I am trying to say is that a small sample will result in low power of the test regardless of the subject-matter interpretation (nature of the experiment). Just be prepared for that. But if the difference is large, detecting it with a low-power test will be less of a problem.

Comment: I've noticed that another bad feature in my data is non-normality, in what measure can this affect the goodness of a t test? Non-normality it cannot be assessed by an HAC regression I think,

Comment: Yes, nonnormality will be a problem. However, it may be difficult to be sure of the actual distribution when your subsamples are as small as 15 points.

Comment: I'm pretty sure about non-normality since my complete time Series it's over 500 observation and nonrmality tests suggest leptokurtosis and a litle bit of skewness. The sub-samples are taken from that series. I was wondering if it is possible to run a non-parametric test with the HAC correction.

Comment: If you test for normality in you whole sample then you are effectively assuming the distribution is the same in all subsamples. Then you would have no reason for splitting into subsamples and investigating those separately.

Comment: It's the nature of my experiment which requires it, to understand if the series shows some behavior 15-20 days before a date and 15-20,days after, I cannot consider the whole sample because I will loose in that case the short-time effect of the event of that specific date...

Comment: Which suggests that the distribution of the data might be changing over time, making a test based on the whole sample irrelevant for a subsample.

Comment: Ok, I understand this point, I've run normality test only for the subsamples; indeed some of them passed the normality test, but most of them are non-normal. This is bad for the inference via the t-test. Honestly I can't see any solution, if I use a non-parametric test, I cannot take into account autocorrelation and non-constant variance, if I use the HAC regression I cannot deal with non-normality...

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not see a solution either. It looks as if the data sample is too small and the structure too complicated to make any inference that one could have a decent degree of confidence in.

Comment: I can run both non parametric tests and HAC regression, compare the results and try to sketch some approximate conclusion. Can a permutation test or bootstrapping be of any help in this case?

Comment: I am a little sceptical. The problem is so fundamental (see my last comment) that I doubt there can be any workaround short of exteding the subsample or simplifying the structure. On the other hand, it has been a while since I used permutation tests or bootstrapping, so I cannot make any valuable comments on them.

Comment: My last attempt: what about a transformation of the variable (such as the Box-Cox) to make it normal and then apply the above-quoted procedures? I find some work which use this kind of transformation to apply the classical parametric tests which require normality. What do you think?

Comment: If that gives you normality, then perhaps it can work. You still need to account for autocorrelation, though, and doing this with only 15 observations means pressing your luck. But maybe it can work.

Comment: I will transform my data trying to make them normal, then I will use the suggested HAC regression for autocorrelation and non-constant variance. It is the only solution for the moment. Thank you again, your help was precious!

Comment: Sorry for another criticical input, but data transformations may affect test statistics. For example, a very simple transformation of adding a constant to one time series would of course move the $t$-statistic closer or further away from zero. Do you think Box-Cox transformation will not have an effect by itself? Then even if you could trust the result for transformed data, it would not translate directly to original data...

Comment: Your critiques are precious for the goodness of my experiment. I read that: 
"When normality of Y is tenable, the t-test computed on the Box-Cox transformed variable achieves greater efficiency than the ordinary t-test." (Freeman, Modarres, 2007). 
But in this paper they refer to MLE, whereas I should use OLS, but I think that the result can hold anyway (otherwise I think there are packages to compute HAC errors with the MLE). In another work, Spitzep (1982) seemed to find good results on z-tests and LR tests after the transformation.

Comment: I have noticed that people tend to transform data so as to make it suitable for some model. They estimate the model and draw conclusions, but they often forget that the conclusions hold for transformed data rather than raw data. In many cases, this means answering the wrong question. I don't know if the references you cite take this into consideration. A similar thing in econometrics is structural vs. reduced-form models. People are often interested in structural parameters but estimate reduced-form models. The important thing is to go back to the structural form then, and they do.

Comment: I was thinking that a problem can be the interpretation of the test itself: after I apply the Box-Cox transformation, it's still a test over the simple mean of the samples?

Comment: @Kolmogorovwannabe, I don't know...

Comment: I ideated another strategy. What about a Mann-kendall trend test modified to take into account autocorrelation? If there are significative different trend between the two Series one can conclude that something happened in the chosen date. This test is non-parametric (normality is not needed) and adjusted For autocorrelation, furthermore it doesn't assume constant variance.

Comment: I don't know the test, but it sounds fine from what you write. In any case, I would not expect too much because there is no magic bullet against a short sample.